# Bootstrap tab click issue inside a Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I click one of the tabs inside a Modal, it triggers the show/shown methods of the modal. Inside the modal shown event I have reset the whole form and did some other things.

Now all these operations are performed when the tab is clicked as well. I don't want this to happen and somehow want to stop modal shown method when a tab is clicked.

Added loggers inside the `click` event of tab and `shown` event of modal.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  console.log("The tab is clicked..");
});

$('#new_stack_modal').on('shown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#new_form").reset();

  console.log("The modal is shown..");
});
```

After some workaround I found [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3091) but didn't find a solution yet. Any fix for this issue?

Comment: do you have some codes for us to test, like a jsfiddle?

Comment: Updated. The click of tab actually calls the modal shown event.